# Promise with q framework and the callback pattern in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, q

Even if well documented [q framework](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) is quite hard to understand if you are programming with Node.js for a few days. But I like to learn about it!

```
var Q  = require('q');
var fs = require('fs');

// Make the promise manually (returns a value or throws an error)
var read1 = fs.readFile(fname, enc, function (err, data) {
    if(err) throw err;

    return data;
});

// Convenient helper for node, equivalent to read1?
var read2 = Q.nfbind(fs.readFile);

// Uh?!
var read3 = function (fname, enc) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    fs.readFile(fname, enc, function (error, text) {
        if (error) {
            deferred.reject(new Error(error));
        } else {
            deferred.resolve(text);
        }

        return deferred.promise;
    });
};


// Execute
Q.fncall(read1).then(function (data) {}, function (err) {}).done();
```

Are `read1`, `read2` and `read3` equivalent? Can I use `Q.nfbind` every time the last parameter of a function accept a callback in the style of `function (err, value)`?

Answer (score 11):

You have a few errors in your examples.

#### read1

This is not 'make a promise manually', this is just making a normal asynchronous call. In your code, you call `readFile` immediately, so `read1` would be the return value of `readFile` which is `undefined`. To get a behavior similar to `read2` and `read3` you would need to do something like this:

```
var read1 = function(fname, env, success, error){
  fs.readFile(fname, enc, function (err, data) {
    // Throwing here would just crash your application.
    if(err) error(err);

    // Returning from inside 'readFile' does nothing, instead you use a callback.
    else success(data);
  });
};
```

#### read2

```
// Not equivalent to read1 because of the notes above,
// Equivalent to read3, with the fixes I mention below.
var read2 = Q.nfbind(fs.readFile);
```

#### read3

```
var read3 = function (fname, enc) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    fs.readFile(fname, enc, function (error, text) {
        if (error) {
            // 'error' is already an error object, you don't need 'new Error()'.
            deferred.reject(error);
        } else {
            deferred.resolve(text);
        }

        // HERE: Again returning a value from 'readFile' does not make sense.
        return deferred.promise;
    });

    // INSTEAD: Return here, so you can access the promise when you call 'read3'.
    return deferred.promise.
};
```

You can indeed use `nfbind` on anything that takes a callback as the last parameter.
With my comments, `read2` and `read3` accomplish the same goal, which is to create a function that will take a filename and encoding, and return a promise object.

For those, you can do this:

```
read2('file.txt', 'utf8').then(function (data) {}, function (err) {}).done();
read3('file.txt', 'utf8').then(function (data) {}, function (err) {}).done();
```

For `read1`, you would call it like this:

```
read1('file.txt', 'utf8', function (data) {}, function (err) {});
```

#### Update

Standard promises have evolved a bit since this was answered, and if you are leaning toward `read3`, I'd recommend doing the following:

```
var read4 = function (fname, enc) {
    return Q.promise(function(resolve, reject){
        fs.readFile(fname, enc, function (error, text) {
            if (error) {
                // 'error' is already an error object, you don't need 'new Error()'.
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve(text);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

This is more in line with standard ES6 promises, and with bluebird, so you'll have an easier time with the code moving forward. Using the method mentioned in `read3` also introduces the possibility of synchronously throwing exceptions instead of capturing them in the promise chain, which is usually undesirable. See [the deferred antipattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern).

Comment: Lovely answer. Bonus points for not forgetting the `.done()`! :)